# Can't play audio via Bluetooth speakers

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, speakers

I have a Lenovo X270 laptop with Win10 on it and Logitech Z537 Bluetooth speakers. When ever I try playing audio, from YT or Spotify for example, over Z537 speakers it doesn't work. The video on YT is interrupted and I get the buffering animation and it doesn't move at all and as soon as I switch to some other audio source like my screen speakers to which the laptop is connected everything works fine.

Anything similar happened to someone else? Is there a fix for this?

Comment: See this [note](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/article/Bluetooth-device-does-not-connect-to-the-Z537-speakers?product=a0q3100000AxT70AAF) from Logitech Support

Comment: This is in case the device does not connect to Bluetooth speakers. I can connect without any problem. The problem is that my internet connection is cut off when I connect.